# What is the lower bound of norm of integer vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

Let $\vec v$ be a vector in $\mathbb Z^3$.
Then, what is the lower bound of $\|\vec v\|$? 
I think $\vec v$ is an integer vector, we can find a lower bound, but it is not easy for me to find it.

Actually, I tried to find a bound using a condition that 
$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 3 \sqrt[3] {a^2b^2c^2}$, but it looks so dirty.

Moreover, I tried to find some technique for lattice theory because of $\mathbb Z ^3$ is a lattice, but many books does not say it.
Can we find a lower bound of norm of integer vector?

Comment: Doesn't $a^2+b^2+c^2$ have to be an integer?

Comment: if $\vec v = (a,b,c)$, the norm $||\vec v|| = \sqrt{a^2 +b^2 + c^2}$. so, by the above condition, we may represent $|\vec v|| \ge \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{a^2 b^2c^2}}$. I want to say this.

Comment: You are making things terribly complicated. The vectors in $\Bbb Z^3$ are points like $(3,2,-1)$ and $(0,1,-2)$. In all cases $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is an integer. How can you choose $a$, $b$ and $c$ to make this as small as possible?

Comment: Well,,, I just want to find a formal lower bound

Comment: As Lord Shark mentions, you are overlooking a very clear answer that gives you the smallest that norm can possibly be

Comment: Oh, I got it. sorry